# Getting the n element of each list in a defaultdict

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, collections, defaultdict

I have a `defaultdict(list)` of:

```
d_int = defaultdict(type, {0: [1,2,3,4,5], 1: [6,7,8,9,10], 2: [11,12,13,14,15]})
```

Is there a pythonic way to save each n element in each list into a new array so I have something like this?:

```
a = [1,6,11]
b = [2,7,12]
c = [3,8,13]
d = [4,9,14]
e = [5,10,15]
```

Comment: Iterate on the keys of the dictionary, just like you would with any dictionary.  That's the pythonic way of using a dictionary.

Comment: `type` isn't a valid `default_factory` argument for `defaultdict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are not considered ordered. However, one way to get the output you desire is to construct a `collections.OrderedDict` of your `collections.defaultdict` object, then apply some `zip` magic:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

d_int = OrderedDict(sorted(defaultdict(list, {0: [1,2,3,4,5],
                           1: [6,7,8,9,10], 2: [11,12,13,14,15]}).items()))

dict(enumerate(zip(*d_int.values())))

# {0: (1, 6, 11), 1: (2, 7, 12), 2: (3, 8, 13), 3: (4, 9, 14), 4: (5, 10, 15)}
```

The benefit of this method is that you do not have to extract length of the dictionary and its constituent lists. In addition, `enumerate` and `zip` are both efficient, lazy functions.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will calculate an array `nth_el`, such than `nth_el[i]` contains all the i-th elements:

```
d_int = defaultdict(type, {0: [1,2,3,4,5], 1: [6,7,8,9,10], 2: [11,12,13,14,15]})

nth_el = [[d_int[k][i] for k in range(3)] for i in range(5)]
```

---

Value of `nth_el` :

```
[[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The example output is almost certainly impractical; if we have data of the same kind, put it in a list. Here's one crude example:

```
>>> d_int = defaultdict(type, {0: [1,2,3,4,5], 1: [6,7,8,9,10], 2: [11,12,13,14,15]})
>>> list(zip(*(v for k,v in sorted(d_int.items()))))
[(1, 6, 11), (2, 7, 12), (3, 8, 13), (4, 9, 14), (5, 10, 15)]
```

The steps are as follows: `items` extracts `key,value` pairs from the dictionary. `sorted` then sorts them by key, the `v for k,v in` generator expression discards the keys, `*` distributes the values as individual arguments to `zip` which transposes them. Finally, `list` builds a list from the zip object (which is iterable).